# ASP.NET Core Scoped DbContext (EntityFramework) in Multithreading Environment

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I read a lot about a scoped DbContext (EntityFramework) in a ASP.NET Core environment.

It makes sense to setup the DI framework with a scoped DbContext, due to have one DbContext per request.
Unfortunately this DbContext cannot be used in a Parallel.ForEach loop (or any kind of thread). The DbContext itself is not threadsafe! So I have to be careful using any kind of Task/Thread.

But sometimes its necessary (or useful) to implements something in a Parallel.ForEach (or something like this).
But how can I be sure that my called functions in a Parallel.ForEach dont use any kind of DbContext? Or maybe one day I decide to use a DbContext in some class/functions which is called from a Task, but I dont not recognize it?

There must be a solution for this? Right now it seems that I cannot use the TPL at all (just to be safe) ... but this seems to be very strange.

Isn't there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to inject a `IServiceProvider` and create your own scope for each iteration.

A quick example would look like

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(values, value =>
{
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
        //query context here
    } // The context will be disposed off by the scope
});
```

Serviced acquired through the scope will also be scoped to it (when applicable)

Comment: I got your point. That will work when knowing doing something in parallel. But what about using an already developed component/functionality which uses the same DI configuration. Sometimes you can't change this component where DbContext is already used ...